# Remove columns from dataframe where some of values are NA

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a dataframe where some of the values are NA. I would like to remove these columns.

My data.frame looks like this

```
    v1   v2 
1    1   NA 
2    1    1 
3    2    2 
4    1    1 
5    2    2 
6    1   NA
```

I tried to estimate the col mean and select the column means !=NA. I tried this statement, it does not work.

```
data=subset(Itun, select=c(is.na(colMeans(Itun))))
```

I got an error,

> error : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: Please add an example of what you would like to have as a result. It would also be really helpful to have a fully reproducible example.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The data:

```
Itun <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,1,2,1,2,1), v2 = c(NA, 1, 2, 1, 2, NA))
```

This will remove all columns containing at least one `NA`:

```
Itun[ , colSums(is.na(Itun)) == 0]
```

An alternative way is to use `apply`:

```
Itun[ , apply(Itun, 2, function(x) !any(is.na(x)))]
```

Comment: This will remove rows with `NA`s, not columns.

Comment: @Backlin, but to Sven's benefit, the whole question is really poorly worded and it's not clear what exactly the OP wants to do. Drop the columns? Convert something to zero?

Comment: True. But he never says anything about rows and uses `subset(..., select=...)` so I figured he wants to extract all rows for certain columns.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein: Sorry for my poorly organized words. I would like to extract columns without NAs from a dataframe.

Comment: doesn't this return a logical array, without subsetting the data?

Comment: should it be `Itun[ , colSums(is.na(Itun)) == 0, with = FALSE]`?

Comment: @simone `Itun` is a `data.frame`, not a `data.table`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein sorry I thought I had read data.table in the answer. My mistake

Answer (score 47):

Here's a convenient way to do it using the `dplyr` function `select_if()`. Combine not (`!`), `any()` and `is.na()`, which is equivalent to selecting all columns that don't contain any NA values.

```
library(dplyr)
Itun %>%
    select_if(~ !any(is.na(.)))
```

Comment: I was wondering if you can extract the column names of the removed columns simultaneously. Is this possible?

Comment: I'd split that into two operations. Use `Itun %>% select_if(~ any(is.na(.))) %>% names()`. Then remove columns in second operation using code above.

Comment: great solution. for the cases that collumns should be remove that only have NAs you can use `select_if(~ !all(is.na(.))`

Comment: This solution is very nice but very slow. Itun[ , colSums(is.na(Itun)) == 0] by @Sven-hohenstein is much faster.

Comment: What does it return though if I wanted to have the columns that have NA/NULL ? When I ran the opposite (i.e. without `!`), it returned a bunch of columns that didn't have NAs; the column that had NA was returned along with them, though.

Answer (score 17):

Alternatively, `select(where(~FUNCTION))` can be used:

```
library(dplyr)

(df <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5], y = NA, z = c(1:4, NA)))
#>   x  y  z
#> 1 a NA  1
#> 2 b NA  2
#> 3 c NA  3
#> 4 d NA  4
#> 5 e NA NA

# Remove columns where all values are NA
df %>% 
  select(where(~!all(is.na(.))))
#>   x  z
#> 1 a  1
#> 2 b  2
#> 3 c  3
#> 4 d  4
#> 5 e NA
  
# Remove columns with at least one NA  
df %>% 
  select(where(~!any(is.na(.))))
#>   x
#> 1 a
#> 2 b
#> 3 c
#> 4 d
#> 5 e
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use transpose twice:

```
newdf <- t(na.omit(t(df)))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
data[,!apply(is.na(data), 2, any)]
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `data.frame` version be the same as the `matrix` version, just without the first comma? I get an error (`undefined columns selected`) with your code as it is.

Comment: However, `apply` converts the input to a matrix prior to applying the function, so I prefer to use `sapply` or `lapply` on data frames. Then again so does `is.na` so in this case the input is already a matrix and my first example was actually incorrect! Perhaps the conceptually nices solution is `sapply(data, function(x) !any(is.na(x)))`, but this is really nitpicking.

Answer (score 2):

A base R method related to the `apply` answers is

```
Itun[!unlist(vapply(Itun, anyNA, logical(1)))]
  v1
1  1
2  1
3  2
4  1
5  2
6  1
```

Here, `vapply` is used as we are operating on a list, and, `apply`, it does not coerce the object into a matrix. Also, since we know that the output will be logical vector of length 1, we can feed this to `vapply` and potentially get a little speed boost. For the same reason, I used `anyNA` instead of `any(is.na())`.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative with the `dplyr` package would be to make use of the `Filter` function

```
Filter(function(x) !any(is.na(x)), Itun)
```

with `data.table` would be a little more cumbersome

```
setDT(Itun)[,.SD,.SDcols=setdiff((1:ncol(Itun)),
                                which(colSums(is.na(Itun))>0))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
df <- df[,colSums(is.na(df))<nrow(df)]
```