# R - Delete column if last value is NA

Tags: r, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I want to delete column(s) in R data frame if their last value is NA.

Example data frame is below

```
A   B   C   D
11  10  19  20
22  20  29  40
33  30  39  60
44  NA  NA  80
```

I would like to get the following output (Column B and C dropped because they had NA values in the last row)

```
A   D
11  20
22  40
33  60
44  80
```

Tried but couldn't get any solution to work. Appreciate your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454487/remove-columns-from-dataframe-where-some-of-values-are-na

Comment: `df[, !is.na(df[nrow(df), ])]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Data
df <- read.table(text="A   B   C   D
                       11  10  19  20
                       22  20  29  40
                       33  30  39  60
                       44  NA  NA  80", header=TRUE)

df[-which(is.na(df[nrow(df), ]))]

   A  D
1 11 20
2 22 40
3 33 60
4 44 80

# Suggestion from @alistaire
df[, !is.na(df[nrow(df), ])]
```

Comment: You can just use `!` instead of `-which`.

Comment: Alternately, `tail(df, 1)` like `df[, !is.na(tail(df, 1)) ]`

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. It should be `nrow(df)`.

Comment: Thanks Jason, Frank and alistaire

Answer (score 0):

na.omit() function deletes any rows with missing data.
pp <- data.frame(po=c(10,20,30,40,NA), pi=c(45,65,75,55,85))
pp
na.omit(pp) -- deletes the entire row

na.delete(pp["po"])  --- deletes the entire column with "NA".

Comment: This is true, but the OP needs to test if *the last row* is `NA` and only delete the column in that case. This answer will delete if the `NA` occurs anywhere.